# Attach to process in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I just upgraded from VS 2010 professional to VS 2013 Express for Web and I can't find the Attach to process option that would allow me to debug a web application hosted on an IIS web server.

The option is available in VS 2013 for windows but there's no such thing for the web edition.

Was this feature removed since VS 2010 or is it limited to some VS 2013 editions (other than Express)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Attach To Process [was not supported on Express versions in 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3(v=vs.100).aspx).  The [2013 page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx) doesn't list which SKUs apply, but it's possible that it still isn't available for Express editions.

Comment: VS Express 2013 for Web doesn't have it, but VS Express 2013 for Desktop does

Comment: Just get Visual Studio Community Edition it can do this