# Unable to run tests while attached for debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, visual-studio-2013

We've recently moved to VS2k13 from VS2k10. In VS2k10 we'd often attach to IIS to debug our MVC4 based services by running one, or more, of the tests we've written.

In VS2k13 I can run tests, and run tests in debug, but I can't run the test after I've attached to IIS. Once I attach to the IIS process the entire Test menu grays out. My tests are listed, but I can't run them.

Updates:

- IIS is being run locally on my machine
- I have removed *.testsettings and *.vsmdi files
- This is VS2013 Ultimate

What did I miss?

Comment: I have some vague recollection here... do you have a *.testsettings or .runsettings file in your Visual Studio solution somewhere? If you do, maybe try regenerating those test settings files in Visual Studio 2013 perhaps?

Comment: I've removed the .vsmdi and .testsettings (there was no .runsettings) files and restarted VS2k13 - no change. The menu grays the moment I attach to IIS.

Comment: Is the IIS server on your local development machine or on a remote server?

Comment: Local. And works fine when I do this in VS2010.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341002/attach-to-process-in-visual-studio-express-2013-for-web) any help to you?

Comment: @AndyBrown No, I'm running ultimate (question updated). The Attach to Process menu exists, and functions, but tests cannot be run.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think thats because while testing ASP.NET code it runs as VSTestHost process and in scenarios when you run the App it is associated with the IIS process or in an ASP.NET Development Server process.

Because the test runs in other than the typical test process, you do not have any tests menu options available or Debug option of tests available.